# How does this sample code work? (LL04node)ois.readObject();

Tags: java

I am having trouble figuring out what (LL04node) does and how it affects the ois.readObject(). This a sample code from my data structure class and it talks about how you can write LinkedList data to an OutputStream file. I hope that someone is knowledgeable enough to help me understand this. Thank you.

```
        import java.io.*;
        public class LL04fromDisk
        {
          public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
          {
            FileInputStream   fis = new FileInputStream("linkedListObj.dat");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            LL04mgr stuListMgr = new LL04mgr();

            stuListMgr.head = (LL04node)ois.readObject(); //code is here

            stuListMgr.dispList();

          }
        }

    //=================================================================

    import java.io.*;
    class LL04mgr implements Serializable
    {
      public LL04node head;                          // field

      public LL04mgr()                               // constructor
      {
        head = null;
      }
      //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
      public void addNode(int i, String n)
      {
        LL04node newNode = new LL04node(i, n, head);
        head             = newNode;
      }
      //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

      public void dispList()
      {
        LL04node current = head;

        while(current != null)
          {
            System.out.printf("%3d %-20s\n",current.id, current.name);
            current = current.next;
          }
      }

//===================================================
import java.io.*;
public class LL04node implements Serializable
{
  public int         id;                            //fields
  public String      name;
  public LL04node    next;

  public LL04node(int i, String n, LL04node ptr)    //constructor
  {
    id   = i;
    name = n;
    next = ptr;
  }
}
```

Comment: `in.readObject()` returns an `Object`, and `(LL04node)`typecasts that to `LL04node`. This is rather basic.

Answer (score 0):

I commented on each line, so hope you should be able to understand each part.

First, you import java.io package to use in and out functions.
The details can be found here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html

```
import java.io.*;
public class LL04fromDisk
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
```

Class FileInputStream let you read the file. By below line, you create a FileInputStream by opening "linkedListObj.dat" file, which is an actual file that is on your local machine.

Detailed description about FileInputStream can be found at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("linkedListObj.dat");
```

Now, you have the data in your system. you are going to create the ObjectInputStream object. Using this, you can actually read object. The detail about ObjectInputStream can be found at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html

```
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
```

You created a new LL04mgr object, by calling the constructor. see [1]

```
        LL04mgr stuListMgr = new LL04mgr();
```

Now, you have a reference for your new List, called stuListMgr. The head of the list is null, so my calling readObject method of ois, which is an ObjectInputStream, set the head of the list. see [2]

As you can see, after you read the object by calling readObject() ObjectInputStream class, you can read an object from the stream. Using the casting, you can get the desired type.

In here (LL04node) is a casting, to get your desired type, LL04node.

```
        stuListMgr.head = (LL04node)ois.readObject(); //code is here
```

After setting the head fo the list, call a dispList method, in your LL04mgr class. see [3]

```
        stuListMgr.dispList();

      }
    }
```

This is your another class, called LL04mgr, which is List.

```
import java.io.*;
class LL04mgr implements Serializable
{
```

This class has one public field, called a head. You can get and set this head, outside of the class, because it is public.

```
  public LL04node head;                          // field
```

[1] This is your constructor. By calling this, you can initialize a new list. 
When you create a new object, you call...
ClassName referenceName = new ConstructorName();

```
  public LL04mgr()                               // constructor
  {
    head = null;
  }
```

You can add a node in the front of the list.

```
  public void addNode(int i, String n)
  {
```

When you call this line, you will create a new Node, which reference name is newNode, has an id of i(integer type), name is n(String type), and the next is the current head.

For example, if there is a list of like below (id, name):

(101, john) -> (2, sam) -> (72, joy)

The current head is (101, john).

You want to insert a new node which id is 62, name is java, then you call,
(Assume that you initiated the object(before LL04mgr list = new LL04mgr();)

list.addNode(62, java);

Then, your new linked list will look like

(62, java) -> (101, john) -> (2, sam) -> (72, joy)

```
    LL04node newNode = new LL04node(i, n, head);
    head             = newNode;
  }
```

This method is to print out each node's information from the first.

```
  public void dispList()
  {
```

You do not want to lose the reference to your current head, for this list. So, you copy the head reference.

```
LL04node current = head;
```

Using the while loop, you travel the list from the beginning(head) to the end.

```
while(current != null)
  {
```

Using the System.out.printf, you print out the information about your nodes with "%3d %-20s\n" format. This link shows the reference of printf: https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet

```
System.out.printf("%3d %-20s\n",current.id, current.name);
```

By calling this, you move the pointer that is pointing to the current node to the next node.

```
        current = current.next;
      }
  }
```

This is node class. The list class has a head and each node is linked. I think if you watch a video, you will be able to understand the concept of the Linked List easily.

Here is my favorite video about Linked List!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njTh_OwMljA

```
import java.io.*;
public class LL04node implements Serializable
{
```

As you can see, each node has 3 fields. It has information on its id and name. Also, this node knows who is the next node. If this node is the last one at the list, the next will be null.

```
  public int         id;                            //fields
  public String      name;
  public LL04node    next;
```

This is the constructor of this node class. When the object of a node is created, this constructor needs to be called. Each input will be stored in the node object.

```
  public LL04node(int i, String n, LL04node ptr)    //constructor
  {
    id   = i;
    name = n;
    next = ptr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining that in full detail for me!

Comment: Sure! Hope it helped you!